# Sonar Authentication is failing with LDAP

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

When i Login to Sonar and leave it for sometime and again back to the same page,sonar authentication fails.
    We are using LDAP 0.1 jar file and Sonar 3.3.1 and the configuration in sonar.properties file is mentioned below:

```
 sonar.authenticator.class: org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapAuthenticator

 sonar.authenticator.ignoreStartupFailure: true

 sonar.authenticator.createUsers: true

 ldap.url: ldap://hostname.mycompany.com:389

 ldap.bindDn: QUA01@mycompany.com

 ldap.bindPassword: Password

 ldap.loginAttribute: sAMAccountName

 ldap.userObjectClass: user
```

Answer (score 1):

Sonar 3.3.1 is not more supported, you should migrate to the latest LTS, the 5.6.
You'll also need to upgrade the LDAP plugin to the version 1.5.

See the upgrade guide for more information how to upgrade : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading